# Jquery-mobile 1.4.5 dynamic listview duplicate autodividers

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I have a little problem with my application.
I'm using Jquery-Mobile 1.4.5 and I want to use a listview with autodividers, filled with a SQL field in a PHP variable.

The problem is that autodividers titles are duplicating every time the sql result finds a name with the same first letter.

As you can see in the next link, the image shows 2 autodividers generated with the "I" first letter, and I don't know why the lisview doesn't agroup them in only 1 autodivider.

https://1drv.ms/i/s!AmWUBgKqLm-KhjIOlqMJH9Nu1Odb

This is the code of my main div, wich generate the dynamic autodivider with the php variable:

```
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<h2>Listado de ventas por cliente</h2>
<form class="ui-filterable">
<input id="myFilter" data-type="search" placeholder="Buscar cliente">
</form>
<?php
while ($row = $res->fetch()) {
echo'<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true">
<li><a href="#">'.$row[0].'</a></li>
</ul>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Any help is welcome. Nice day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using multiple `data-autodividers`.Use following code:

```html
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<h2>Listado de ventas por cliente</h2>
<form class="ui-filterable">
<input id="myFilter" data-type="search" placeholder="Buscar cliente">
</form>
  <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-input="#myFilter" data-autodividers="true" data-inset="true">
<?php
while ($row = $res->fetch()) {
echo'<li><a href="#">'.$row[0].'</a></li>';
}
?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude, it was very easy and obvious but Im not very experienced programming. Thanks again man, take care...

Comment: welcum dude ..keep practice